# How to make 65 clusters ? Is k-mean good algorithm to do this?

Tags: clustering, cart, k-means, high-dimensional

I am trying to segment customers based on demographic, behavioral, lifestyle etc into 60-65 segments inline with Claritas Prizm segments [Link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claritas_Prizm)   [Link2](https://claritas360.claritas.com/mybestsegments/#)

I have 1 million records and 264 variables. Reading 68 segments in detail makes me think that it is not just a clustering technique but some rule-based segments are also there. Can anyone please suggest me what should be my approach to get 60-70 clusters as in Prizm

Is unsupervised CART [Link3](http://cybertim.timone.univ-mrs.fr/Members/rgiorgi/DossierPublic/StaffBiostat/.../CURT-BG) will be of help here? Though I have never tried CURT before but read in stackexchange [LINK4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178297/cart-for-unsupervised-learning-clustering) that the process has many challenges and assumptions

Comment: What do you mean by "Reading 68 segments in detail"? What precisely is your question? You can apply any [tag:clustering] algorithm you like after defining a metric on your attributes. [Be aware that high dimensions do not behave like our low dimensional intuition would suggest, so high dimensional clustering is dubious.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/99171/1352)

Comment: By 68 Segments I mean the one described by Claritas (Please refer Link 1 and 2 above). My question is to understand the approach so that I will be able to create 60-70 clusters more or less describing the segments as in Claritas.  I tried k-means but results are not expected. Now I am planning to create a subset of data based on some rule (such as high income etc) and then run k-means to the subset.  Can I reduce dimensions using PCA then run K-means?

Comment: Unfortunately, we won't be able to tell you how Claritas defined their segments. Yes, you can run PCA and then apply k-means. Whether this is useful we cannot tell.

Comment: Actually most likely it is *not* meaningful. And the purpose of Claritas is to have a consistent set of groups across multiple data sets and not to cluster them differently each time.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse : Do you mean instead of clustering if I do rule based segmentation, It will give better result. What I observed from Claritas segments is that they are using 30-35 variables. I can segment my data based on rule as per definition of each Claritas's segment. Is this is the correct  way of doing? When aim is to segment my data similar to the segments of Claritas.

Comment: Yes, if you want their segments, use their rules, obviously.